# Is $|A\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |01\rangle$ a valid quantum state?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

Is $|A\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} |01\rangle$ a valid quantum state? Or does a quantum state need to be a superposition of the entire basis, i.e.,
$$ |A\rangle  = \frac{1}{2} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |01\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |10\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |11\rangle$$

Comment: One way to check your work computationally is with Qiskit's `Statevector.is_valid()` https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector#is_valid

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the state $ |A\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |01\rangle $ is indeed a valid quantum state. In quantum mechanics, a valid quantum state can be any normalized linear combination of basis states.

The two states you've mentioned, $$|A\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |01\rangle$$ and $$ |A\rangle = \frac{1}{2} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |01\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |10\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |11\rangle $$ are both valid quantum states, and they represent different superpositions of the basis states $|00\rangle $ and $ |01\rangle $.

The state $$|A\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |01\rangle $$  represents a superposition where the system is in a state that is a linear combination of $|00\rangle $ and $ |01\rangle $, with equal probability amplitudes $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $.

On the other hand, the state $$ |A\rangle = \frac{1}{2} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |01\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |10\rangle + \frac{1}{2} |11\rangle $$ represents a superposition where the system is in a state that is a linear combination of all four basis states $ |00\rangle $, $|01\rangle $, $|10\rangle $, and $ |11\rangle $, with equal probability amplitudes $\frac{1}{2} $.

Both states are valid quantum states.

Comment: Very nice answer! And just to add a little bit: a very easy way to check if a state is valid is, if all the terms contain orthogonal states (e.g. taking the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|01\rangle$ example, we see that $|00\rangle$ and  $|01\rangle$ are indeed orthogonal), then you just check whether the sum of the square of the amplitudes is equal to 1 (e.g. $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|^2+|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}||^2=1)$

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer from Yet another Random Guy, you can see for yourself by recreating the state programmatically (here using the Amazon Braket SDK):

````python
from braket.circuits import Circuit
from braket.devices import LocalSimulator

circuit = Circuit().i(0).h(1).state_vector()
LocalSimulator().run(circuit).result().values[0]
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Given that we are talking about the state of 2 qubits, the canonical basis of the state space is $$(|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|11\rangle)$$

A physically valid quantum state is just a vector in that vector space whose Hermitian norm is 1 - normalized-, ie
$$|\psi\rangle=\alpha_1|00\rangle + \alpha_2 |01\rangle + \alpha_3|10\rangle + \alpha_4 |11\rangle $$
$\forall i,\quad\alpha_i \in\mathbb{C}$ with
$$\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = |\alpha_1|^2+|\alpha_2|^2+|\alpha_3|^2+|\alpha_4|^2 = 1$$

Comment: Is *Hermitian Norm* some well-defined and regularly used terminology/quantity/name? I have never heard the term *Hermitian Norm* in any literature before.

Comment: If you just meant the regular Euclidean norm using the inner product, technically, you are missing a square root. We define it as

$$|| |\psi\rangle || = \sqrt{\langle \psi | \psi \rangle}\,.$$

Comment: Since the condition is to be equal to 1 it is completely equivalent to use the square of the norm or the norm. Much more readable without the square root. And Euclidean for me refers to real vector space not complex. I did not make a study of the use of the word Hermitian, but obviously you understood the meaning this is only what is important to me.

Comment: Since you used it, I was just trying to learn something new, a quantity that I had not come across before called the *hermitian norm*. So, that's why I just asked for clarification.

Comment: This is  a word used in French maths textbooks more than English ones, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also, I agree that square root does not matter here, but I believe it is essential to be precise since you are saying the term *norm* and then just defining the inner product $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$. It would not matter in this case, but someone might think norm means $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$ by reading this answer and may use it in other instances in which square root does matter. I believe that it is vital to be precise when writing answers.